# Receiving empty List in fragment with navigation args

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I am passing an object of a Model class from one fragment another fragment. I can successfully retrieve "customerName" in receiving fragment but the List is always empty.
This is the model class:

```
@Parcelize
data class Bill (var customerName:String,var listOfStart:List<Int>):Parcelable
```

Code snippet of Sending Fragment:

```
 customerName = etName.editText?.text.toString()
            start = etStart.editText?.text.toString().toInt()
            listOfStart.add(start)

            val bill=Bill(customerName,listOfStart)
            Log.d("Test", "Name  when sending: "+customerName)
            Log.d("Test", "List contents when sending: "+listOfStart)
            val action: NavDirections =HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToResultFragment(bill)
            findNavController().navigate(action)
```

Code snippet of Receiving Fragment:

```
 private val fragmentArgs by navArgs<ResultFragmentArgs>()
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
{

   Log.d("Test", "Name when receiving": "+fragmentArgs.args.customerName)
   Log.d("Test", "List contents when receiving": "+fragmentArgs.args.listOfStart)
 }
```

Log cat

```
2020-10-26 12:16:17.786 14893-14893/tahir.billcalculator D/Test: Name  when sending: Nametest
2020-10-26 12:16:17.786 14893-14893/tahir.billcalculator D/Test: List contents when sending: [12]
2020-10-26 12:16:17.878 14893-14893/tahir.billcalculator D/Test: Name when receiving: Nametest
2020-10-26 12:16:17.878 14893-14893/tahir.billcalculator D/Test: List contents when receiving: []
```

Comment: hello from your logcat it's visible that the first time you got your list `List contents when sending: [12]` here but in second you didn't receive anything that means might be there is some issue while adding data in the list second time. I would suggest try having debug point at this `val action: NavDirections =HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToResultFragment(bill)` and in your `viewCreated` method to check whether data passed and received is proper or not.

Comment: I have checked as you suggested. It is passing data correctly. But on receiving side, only name is received and list is empty

Comment: Send the definition of HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToResultFragment(bill) . What you are doing in this method